# Admin rights for a standard user in OS X

Tags: macos, permission

I want to create a user with OS X restrictions (Parental Control), which would still be allowed to install applications in the standard Applications folder using its password.

Is it possible? How should I do it?

Comment: Do you want the admin user to be restricted by parental controls?

Comment: Why don't you create a standard user account with restrictions, log on to it, and install applications in the Applications folder using the user/pass of the admin account?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend that you try to put in such a scheme. If you wish to use restrictions, you would generally not want the restricted user to install any application either (for security reasons).

Normally, a non-admin user cannot install applications in the system applications folder at `/Applications` since it's owned by user `root` and group `admin`. However, a non-admin user can install applications under the home directories (`~/Applications`), but those applications would be available only to that specific user (certain applications that are designed to be in `/Applications` or those using installer packages to write into system locations may not work well in such a case).

If you wish to allow a non-admin user to install applications into `/Applications`, then you can add that user to the `admin` group from `Terminal.app` (instead of going to System Preferences and allowing the user to be an administrator). Keep in mind that a user who can install applications into `/Applications` can also remove applications from there (intentionally or unintentionally).

Comment: basicaly i need enable parental control with NO function for disabling. So i cant do this if i will not do a standard user but i need administrative priveleges for install or remove apps and edit some system file and no more. i know there have another system accaunt root. it possible give all priveleges for root for editing parental control and keep some priveleges for standard user or keep administrator accaunt and enable parental control with no function of disabling it.

Comment: now i can do this if have two accaunts one administrator and one standard and if i want to install app i need type a admin name and pass then if it correct it will install but i need other thing.

Comment: From terminal, use this command to add the standard user to the admin group (substitute "standarduser" with the standard user's id):  

`sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a standarduser -t user admin`

Comment: There are ways for a non-admin user to run Finder as `root` (with a `sudo` command) so that you can install into `/Applications`, but they would end up masking the currently logged in user's folders and possibly result in confusion.